# How to handle errors using the Tedious driver with Node

Tags: node.js, sql-server, typescript, tedious

**The Problem:**

I keep running into issues with typos in my SQL queries and the tedious driver isn't helping much. When there are errors, it does a fine job telling me the type of error and what went wrong, but the stack trace never contains any of my project files. This is making it difficult to debug, especially when I'm making multiple queries in the same function. I'm currently using the mssql library, but experienced the same problem using tedious directly. Plus, mssql isn't mentioned in the error's stack at all, so I figure it's not the problem.

**What I've Tried:**

- Looking for issues on the [tedious GitHub page](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues)
- Added a `conn.on('error')` listener, which doesn't appear to do anything.
- Added `process.on()` listeners for 'uncaughtException' and 'unhandledRejection'.
- Moved the initialization of the `ConnectionPool` into it's own function to try and catch the error there. No luck.

**Some Code:**

Here's a barebones example of what I'm using to run the queries:

```js
async function dbConnect() {
  const conn = await new ConnectionPool(dbConfig).connect();

  conn.on('error', error => {
    console.error('*Connection Error:', error);
  });

  return conn;
}

async function runQuery() {
  const conn = await dbConnect();

  await conn.request().query(`SELECT Thing FROM Place`);
  await conn.close();
}

runQuery()
  .then(results => {
    console.log(results);

    process.exit(0);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);

    process.exit(1);
  });
```

**The Error:**
[image: An error message without the correct stack]

Hopefully, this is something that's possible. If not, is there a different Node driver for SQL Server that someone's come up with?

**Edit: Added an error listener on `request`**

```js
async function dbConnect() {
  const conn = await new ConnectionPool(dbConfig).connect();
  const request = new Request(conn);

  conn.on('error', error => {
    console.error('*Connection Error:', error);
  });

  request.on('error', error => {
    console.error('*Request Error:', error);
  });

  return request;
}

async function runQuery() {
  const request = await dbConnect();

  await request.query(`SELECT Thing FROM Place`);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting up a `request.on('error')` listener? Typically, SQL batch errors are treated differently from connection errors (which relate to issues with the connection to the DB instance). See https://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/api-request.html

Comment: No luck there either. I'll put my modified code in an edit up top.

Comment: Good question, looking for more details on this topic.